# What happens to the transactional replication if azure sql Vm(publisher and distributor) is stopped and restarted from portal?

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-database, transactional-replication, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am a newbie...I have azure sql vm and sql managed instance. I have setup transactional replication between them. Now if I stop the vm from the portal will the replication still continue after restarting the sql server vm? or will I have to reset the transactional replication?

Comment: Depending on how long (less than 72 hrs), replication will accumulate commands and you wont be able to trucate the log. Once the server is up, it will eventually catchup. If it is passed 72 or 48 hrs, it will expire and you will have to reinitialize replication.

Comment: Now after starting my sql server vm ...In job activity monitor, the subscriber agent job and log reader agent show success but distributor agent job is not showing last run. In launch replication monitor the log reader is not running...what should I do and What it means?

Comment: I got the answer after restarting vm we also need to reinitialize all subscription-> restart sql server agent->take snapshot->start log reader->done